# PhpStorm 2017.1 freezes on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, ubuntu-16.10

I had no problem with PhpStorm on Windows 10 for almost 2 years. Now, when I installed Ubuntu 16.10, there is some strange magic going over here.

I've got a project which I've newly created from existing sources. Everything went fine for that moment. Problem occurs when I want to add new server in `Settings -> Deployment` tab. The "Add Server" popup appears and after filling Name and clicking "OK" button, PhpStorm freezes for a good couple of seconds. Same thing when I want to enter and edit some data inside that particular item from this tab. PhpStorm freezes so good that I cannot even close "Settings" popup :D.

I'm turning PhpStorm on from terminal with `sudo pstorm` command.

Any ideas?

Comment: The best way ... since it could be your system specific issue: 1) Collect idea.log and other performance info as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems 2) Submit support ticket (`Submit a request` link on top of the page: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm )

Comment: @LazyOne I've also got other problem with deployment. Maybe it's related. I've got one deployment item set (with filled server, password etc.). With that thing, PhpStorm almost always ask me to enter User name and Password data (https://i.imgur.com/0ONLjJT.png). It's not saving my previously set (also in that window) data.

Comment: For your last comment/screenshot: Please switch to the most safe **KeePass** option in `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords`. If you prefer using Keychain instead -- you may either try to install some additional component (e.g. `sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring`) .. or it may not yet supported for your setup (e.g. KWallet -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163275). Your `idea.log` should have hints in this regard.

Comment: Ok, I think that's it. Works okay, even the 1st problem. Why could be wrong with that initial KeePass?

Comment: What "initial KeePass"? Before 2016.3 (or maybe 2017.1 -- not too sure) passwords were stored using some local config file(s) (DB separately, deployment separately etc). Now it's unified place/platform which is more safe/convenient for end user in general: on Windows KeePass is the only option; on Linux/Mac native Keychain is available as well. But because there are some many different Linux distribs around, not all of them have needed libraries/not all implementations are supported - hence the "KeePass as the safest option".

Comment: See initial tickets if you are interested: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65077 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-37015 3) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91517 . All tickets -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BPassword%20Safe%7D%20

Comment: So .. what option do you use right now -- KeePass or Native Keychain? I have found 2 tickets on "freeze" and "slow" subject: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167107 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165017 -- they both happen on Linux with Native Keychain option

Comment: So now I'm using "In KeePass" option, where my database lies in this path "/root/.PhpStorm2017/config/c.kdbx". The "In native Keychain" option was giving me above problems, which I described earlier in this Question.

Comment: And like in one of above issues, PhpStorm also (before) were asking me always about Bitbucket login and password (although I was giving those data earlier). Could be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer lies in comments, thanks to @LazyOne:

> Please switch to the most safe KeePass option in Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords. If you prefer using Keychain instead -- you may either try to install some additional component (e.g. sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring) .. or it may not yet supported for your setup (e.g. KWallet -- youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163275).

For now I'm using "In KeePass" option, where my database lies in this path "*/root/.PhpStorm2017/config/c.kdbx*". The "*In native Keychain*" option was giving me problems which I described in the question.